# getting id of element onclick from loops

Tags: html, button, onclick, velocity

Let's start with the array, suppose that I have this array set in my velocity

```
#set ($test= [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "sample1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "sample2"
  }
  ])
```

then I call with using a loop as seen below:

```
#foreach($test in $test)
<div class="test">  
  <span class="test-name">$test.name</span>
  <button>Sample Button</button>
</div>
#end
```

what can I use so that the `$test.id` of the button clicked can be retrieved so I may be able to view it in another page or a modal by using an array because I'm well aware you can set and add elements into an array in velocity like this:

```
#set ($clickedArray = [] )
#set ($holder = $clickedArray.add($test.id))
```

I just need to retrieve the clicked button's id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the id to an other page that should be loaded after you pressed the button. You could use a hidden field in order to send your id as GET param to the second page

```
#foreach($test in $test)
    <div class="test">  
    <span class="test-name">$test.name</span>
        <form method="GET" action="otherPage.html">
            <input type="hidden" name="yourParam" value="$test.id">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="buttonname" />
        </form>
    </div>
#end
```

If you want to pass your id to a JavaScript method in order to show a modal on the same page, then you could do this:

```
<script>
    function doSomething(id){
        alert("Your id is: " + id);
    }
</script>

#foreach($test in $test)
<div class="test">  
  <span class="test-name">$test.name</span>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="buttonname" onclick="doSomething('$test.id')"/>
</div>
#end
```